# How can you determine if a point is next to the QTabBar of a QTabWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtabwidget

I have a custom QTabWidget with a custom QTabBar.  I need to determine if a point is in the area next to the QTabBar.  (see image)

[image]

I have a function that accepts a point representing a mouse cursor position.  Using the `mapFromGlobal()` function and the `QTabBar.rect().contains()` function I can easily determine if the point is inside the QTabBar or not.  I then thought it would be easy to determine if the point was inside the tab content or not in a similar way.  However, the "page" is larger than the content widget.  So by eliminating the QTabBar and the tab content, I can only determine if the point is inside the area shown below:

[image]

How can I determine if the point is next to the QTabBar as shown in the first image?  Is there a way that I can access the underlying "page" that contains the tab content?

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: I was looking for a conceptual answer and I just figured one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after posting I realized that there was a very simple solution.

After mapping the mouse cursor point from global, determine if the `QPoint.y()` value is less than `QTabBar.height()`.